# How to send file to my WebService based on Spring Boot from Angular 5 client?

Tags: typescript, spring-boot, angular5, multipartform-data, sendfile

I've spent a lot of time to solve my problem but without success.

I have an Angular 5 client and I want to send a file to my SpringBoot web service so that I can handle with that file on web service side.

My template:

```
<div class="dropdown-content">
                        <label (click)="openDialog()">Upload from xls</label>
                        <label>Save to xls</label>
                        <label>Link 3</label>
                        <input type="file" class="inputFile" style="display:none" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
</div>
```

I'd like to have the possibility to choose a file after clicking on a label Upload from xls:

```
openDialog() {
    let myInputFile = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.inputFile');
    myInputFile.click();
  }

  //This method is called after choosing a file
  handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    var file = this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
    this.uploadFileService.pushFileToStorage(file);
  }
```

Next we call this.uploadFileService.pushFileToStorage(file);

```
@Injectable()
export class UploadFileService {

    constructor(private http: Http, private globals: Globals, private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    pushFileToStorage(file) {

    let headers = new Headers();
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create header

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file); // Append file to formdata
    console.log(file);

    const req = this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:' + this.globals.tomcatPort + '/utils/saveFromFile', JSON.stringify(formData));

    req.subscribe((data) => {

        console.log(data); // Sucess response
    }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {

        // Erro response
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
            //client side error
            console.log('An error occured: ', err.error.message);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Backend returned code', err.status, 'body was ', err.error);
        }
    })
```

On the WebService side, my StorageController looks like (temporarily, for tests)

```
    @RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@RequestMapping("/utils")
public class StorageController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/saveFromFile", consumes = "multipart/form-data", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void saveFromFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile) {
        System.out.println(multipartFile);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipart = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipart.setMaxUploadSize(3 * 1024 * 1024);
        return multipart;
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(0)
    public MultipartFilter multipartFilter() {
        MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter();
        multipartFilter.setMultipartResolverBeanName("multipartReso‌​lver");
        return multipartFilter;
    }
}
```

Currently I get the error:

> Failed to load http://localhost:8180/utils/saveFromFile: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

I have problem with CORS only when I'm trying to send a file.

Thank you in advance!
Mateusz

Comment: You have created headers but not passing from request. You need to pass `options` from get service

Answer (score 1):

In `UploadFileService` you need to import

`import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http'`

And while calling POST service you can do like if you want to set `Authorization` header with some token then this is the way to set header in general. And again if you want to add more then simply append them

```
 const req = this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:' + 
 this.globals.tomcatPort + '/utils/saveFromFile', JSON.stringify(formData), 
 {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Basic jfghghjbhjb')});
```

If you don't want to use inline headers then you can create it's separate object like below

`const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Basic jfghghjbhjb')`

and you can use this

`const req = this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:' + 
     this.globals.tomcatPort + '/utils/saveFromFile', JSON.stringify(formData), 
     {headers: headers});`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I solved my problem in very easy way:

Angular template:

```
<div class="dropdown-content">
                        <label (click)="openDialog()">Upload from xls</label>
                        <label>Save to xls</label>
                        <label>Link 3</label>
                        <input type="file" class="inputFile" style="display:none" (change)="handleFileInput($event)">
                    </div>
```

Angular component:

```
openDialog() {
    let myInputFile = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.inputFile');
    myInputFile.click();
  }

  //This method is called after choosing a file
  handleFileInput(event) {
    var file = this.fileToUpload = <File>event.target.files[0];
    this.uploadFileService.pushFileToStorage(file);
  }
```

Angular Service:

```
pushFileToStorage(file) {
        const fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file, file.name);
        this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:' + this.globals.tomcatPort + '/utils/saveFromFile', fd)
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.dataStorageService.getDictionaryItems();
            })
    }
```

and in WebService in my Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/saveFromFile", consumes = "multipart/form-data", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void saveFromFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        convFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
        fos.write(file.getBytes());
        fos.close();

        storageService.saveWordsFromFile(convFile);

    }
```

And that's all. It works!